# Refer to global dynamic range in other workbook

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

**My Problem**

Suppose I have a named range (`xxx` say) in `Workbook1` (on workbook scope) which refers to a dynamically determined area, something like:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),1)
```

Now I want to refer to this range in `VBA`:

```
Sub t()
    Debug.Print Range("xxx").Address
End Sub
```

This works like a charm. However, when I now change the active workbook (for example by adding a new one), the above line will fail:

```
Sub t()
    Workbooks.Add
    Debug.Print Range("xxx").Address
End Sub
```

**My Workaround**

My workaround for now is to re-activate `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Sub t()
    Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Debug.Print Range("xxx").Address
End Sub
```

**My Question**

Is this the only way to achieve this? I was trying to access the range via `ThisWorkbook.Names("xxx").RefersToRange` but this does not work either, as the range is dynamically determined. And unfortunately there is nothing like `ThisWorkbook.Range("xxx")`.

So to make a long question short: How do I refer to a globally named dynamic range regardless of the current focus? Is the only way to change the scope from `Workbook` to `Worksheet`?

Answer (score 1):

Even if `xxx` is within the workbook scope you can access it within the sheets scope.

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("xxx").Address
```

This only works on the sheet where the offset points to (sheet1 here).

---

If you just use this to find the used range of column A then I suggest to easily solve this with VBA only:

```
Debug.Print Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Address
```

Comment: +1 Did not know that. Now I "just" have to find out on which sheet `xxx` is defined, becasue I also cannot guarantee that this sheet is the active one. Any ideas?

Comment: If `xxx` is in the workbook scope then **any** sheet in this workbook will do the job whatever which one is active. Workbook scope is accessible in **every** sheet of this workbook.

Comment: Nope, just tried it out. `?activeworkbook.sheets(2).range("xxx").value` worked, while `?activeworkbook.sheets(1).range("xxx").value` did work. (needless to say `xxx` was defined global but referred to a cell on sheet 1)

Comment: I see only the chance to do it with the correct sheet name like this `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` or to use VBA to find the used range in column A. It looks like it is a limitation that `ThisWorkbook.Names("xxx").RefersToRange` does not work with a volatile function like `offset`.